# Test a Rails 4 Engine with the dummy app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I want to test a Rails 4 Engine by using the dummy app, but I've no idea how to do that.

My engine only has one model named `Event`. At first I decomment the code in the `event_test.rb`:

```
test "the truth" do
  assert true
end
```

Now I tried to launch the tests from the folder of the dummy application but I don't know which command I have to use. I tried `rake test` (nothing happens) and `rake test test/models/<engine-name>/event_test.rb` (Error: rake aborted! Don't know how to build task...).

How can I launch the tests of my engine?

Comment: run `rake test` from engine dir.

Comment: Oh, that works. But can I test everything (controllers, views, ect.) this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dummy` application only mounted point for you `engine`. You don't need run test from `dummy` dir.
Your (controllers, views, ect.) from `engine` should available in `dummy` app and (controllers, views, ect.) from `dummy` should available in `engine`.

Comment: @Kagutsuchi my pleasure, i love engine and build every day. read [doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html)